# Invalid identifier when passing SQL result into an array in a shell script

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I am trying to store SQL query result into an array in a shell script but I face an invalid identifier error when I run my .sh

Could you please check what matter in my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

echo Start Executing SQL commands

array=$(sqlplus -s apps/apps << eof
SET PAGESIZE 0;
SELECT directory_name from all_directories where directory_name like '%XXBP%';
eof)


printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

This is the error I get:

[image: Screenshot of the error i get]

I know the problem comes from my operator % but I need it to restrict the result of my query.

Comment: I see like search field '%XXBP%' but in error message  "%XXBP%" double quotes thats is the issue ... it should be in single quotes

Comment: I wrote my code with single quote as you can see above

Comment: Wow.  That is a major ksh88 bug, Good reason to use ksh93.  As an aside, your array variable is not declared as an array (`typeset -a`) so the ${array[@]} gives the contents of the variable.  ${array} or $array would work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [this very specific ksh bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569857/ksh88-changing-single-quotes-to-double-quotes-inside-heredocs) where here-documents silently convert single-quotes to double-quotes. You could try the workaround in that answer, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

echo Start Executing SQL commands

# put the single-quotes in a variable to prevent the here-document from converting them to double
STR="'%XXBP%'"

array=$(sqlplus -s apps/apps << eof
SET PAGESIZE 0;
SELECT directory_name from all_directories where directory_name like $STR;
eof)

printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you it seems working. I just did not understood why